# "IEnumerable<samplemodel> model" values fill to another model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following controller method to get data which as parameters as `IEnumerable<samplemodel> model`

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create_Template(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {
        return View(...);
    }
```

this is `ProductsPropertiesVM` model class

```
public class ProductsPropertiesVM
{


    public int Property_ID { get; set; }
    public string Property_Title { get; set; }
    public string Property_Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public string Product_Name { get; set; }       
    public string Product_Description { get; set; }       
    public string Prodcut_Features { get; set; }
    public string Unique_Selling_Propositions { get; set; }        
    public string Business_Case_Feasibity_Study { get; set; }
    public string Sharia_Resolution_and_Requirement_for_Product { get; set; }
    public string Approved_Accounting_Entries { get; set; }
    public string Listing_of_Risk_Related_Procedures { get; set; }
    public string Legal_Requirement { get; set; }
    public string Listing_of_Internal_Procedures_for_Review { get; set; }
    public string Product_Statistics_Targeted_Segment { get; set; }
    public string Product_Statistics_Sales_Volume { get; set; }
    public string Product_Statistics_Profitability { get; set; }
    public string Product_Statistics_Annual_Growth_Rate { get; set; }
    public string Relevent_Case_Studies { get; set; }

}
```

to this controller , data are passing like below images

Image one : 10 elements [0-9 indexes]

[image]

Image two : Properties of 0th index element

[image]

I want to select limited element's properties which is `IsChecked` property `True` of this 0-9 indexed elements , and return it

to assign that limited element's properties I created another model class like below

```
public class TemplateProperties
{
    public int Property_ID { get; set; }
    public string Property_Title { get; set; }
    public string Property_Value { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

So then I try to do something like below

**Approach 1:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create_Template(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {

        IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample = model.Where(y => y.IsChecked).Select(y => new
        {
            sample.IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
            sample.Name = y.Property_Title,
            sample.PropertyValue = y.Property_Value

        });

        return View(sample);
    };
```

but this getting compile error

**Approach 2:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create_Template(IEnumerable<ProductsPropertiesVM> model)
    {

        var sample = model.Where(y => y.IsChecked).Select(y => new
        {
            IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
            Name = y.Property_Title,
            PropertyValue = y.Property_Value

        });

        return View(sample);
    };
```

but this approach once I goto view model values not bind to  TemplateProperties model,

What can I do to correct this

**Edit**

once I use @Rahuls solution , almost all the compilation errors gone away , then I created Details view , but once I run this got an error page like this

[image]

Comment: try with `.ToList<BrochureTemplateProperties>()` after your linq query.

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you said this awful url became a problem to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach 1 is correct, you are getting error because you are projecting an `anonymous` type and storing it in `IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties>` . Simply project the type `BrochureTemplateProperties` like this:-

```
 IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample = model.Where(y => y.IsChecked)
        .Select(y => new BrochureTemplateProperties
        {
            IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
            Name = y.Property_Title,
            PropertyValue = y.Property_Value
        });
```

**Update:**

Okay so your View is expecting `Models.BrochureTemplateProperties` but you are passing `IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties>` so you will need to fetch the first matching object. Simply add `FirstOrDefault` at the end:-

```
 .Select(y => new BrochureTemplateProperties
            {
                IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
                Name = y.Property_Title,
                PropertyValue = y.Property_Value
            }).FirstOrDefault(); //here
```

Comment: this could be okay Ill try

Comment: @kez, While Rahul Singh is correct, your approach is not. You should never have a parameter which is a collection of complex objects in a GET method. Apart from the awful url your generating, your can easily exceed the query string limit and throw an exception.

Comment: once I use your solution allmost all the compilation errors gone away , then I created Details view , but once I run this got a error page like this 
http://s16.postimg.org/gvpldz61h/errorz.jpg

Comment: @kez - I can't see the image. Also Stephen is absolutely correct, I didn't noticed you are doing this in GET request, if possible try changing your approach.

Comment: @kez - Nope I am not able to, they are blocked.

Comment: I'll add to question then

Comment: @kez - Check my update, you will have to add `FirstOrDefault` to fetch the first object your are currently passing a list but your model expects only single object of `BrochureTemplateProperties`.

Comment: but then comes error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Project_Name.Models.BrochureTemplateProperties' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project_Name.Models.BrochureTemplateProperties>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @kez - Yeah because now we are returning just 'BrochureTemplateProperties' change return type to 'BrochureTemplateProperties sample' instead of 'IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties> sample'

Comment: but here I have problem how to select rest of the checked properties, this one select first item only

Answer (score 0):

Try with this -

```
var sample = model.Where(y => y.IsChecked).Select(y => new
    {
        IsChecked = y.IsChecked,
        Name = y.Property_Title,
        PropertyValue = y.Property_Value

    }).ToList<BrochureTemplateProperties>();
```

Comment: getting this kind a comple time error `'IEnumerable<<anonymous type: bool IsChecked, string Name, string PropertyValue>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList<BrochureTemplateProperties>(IEnumerable<BrochureTemplatePrope‌​rties>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<BrochureTemplateProperties>'`